# What is more efficient: RxTextView.textChanges or doOnTextChanged?

Tags: android, android-edittext, rx-binding

What is better when need to listen/watch/observe value of edit text

- using **RxBinding** (RxTextView.textChanges)
- using **doOnTextChanged** (  reviewEditText.doOnTextChanged { _, _, _, _ ->
          checkButtonState()
      })

I have a screen with several **EditTextViews** and want to **disable/enable** a *button* based on **content** of these Views, so what is **more efficient** to do this?

Answer (score 0):

If you use RxKotlin, I would suggest using **RxBinding** because it gives you the ability to combine validations in an easy way:

```
disposable = Observables.combineLatest(
        emailEditTextObservable.map { isEmailValid() }, 
        phoneEditTextObservable.map { isPhoneValid() }) { validEmail, validPhoneNumber ->
        validEmail && validPhoneNumber
    }.subscribe { button.isEnabled = it }
```